# How to make 3 TCN in parallele with 3 filter lengths?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to use three TCN in parallel with diffrent filter sizes. So my model look like this:

```
input_Sig = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,size))
# reshape_Sig = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((size, 1))(input_Sig)
tcn_L_F3 = TCN(nb_filters=filternb, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',nb_stacks=1,dilations = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ])(input_Sig)
tcn_L_F5 = TCN(nb_filters=filternb, kernel_size=5, activation='relu',nb_stacks=1,dilations = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ])(input_Sig)
tcn_L_F7 = TCN(nb_filters=filternb, kernel_size=7, activation='relu',nb_stacks=1,dilations = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16])(input_Sig)

combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([tcn_L_F3, tcn_L_F5,tcn_L_F7],axis=1)

MLP_Layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(size, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform")(combined)
MLP_Layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(MLP_Layer1)
MLP_Layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(size//2, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform")(MLP_Layer1)
MLP_Layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(MLP_Layer2)
MLP_Layer3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer="uniform")(MLP_Layer2)
DLmodel = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_Sig], outputs=[MLP_Layer3])
DLmodel.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(0.001), metrics=['accuracy', 'mse'], run_eagerly=True)
```

When I try to fit this model with the data, I get this error:

```
{ValueError}Shapes (10, 200, 2) and (10, 600, 2) are incompatible
```

It seems I cannot parallelize 3 TCN correctly. I think there is something wrong with the concatenation?

the TCN come from  [link to TCN](https://github.com/zhong110020/keras-tcn)